# atoi() выдает ошибку "аргумент типа char несовместим с параметром типа const char*"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{   
    char sym = '5';
    int res = atoi(sym); // error        
  
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Пробовал скастовать к `const char*`, но бросает исключение.

Comment: `std::atoi()` ожидает получить обычную нуль-терминированную C-строку. Это `char sym = '5';` не С-строка, и каст тут не поможет. Пишите, например так: `const char* sym = "5";`

Comment: понял, спасибо! А есть аналог работающий с char?

Comment: Если нужно преобразовать одиночный `char` в число, то проще всего, как и сказано в ответе, вычесть символ `0`: `int res = sym-'0';`. Но можно сделать и что-нибудь такое: `int res = std::stoi(std::string(1, sym));`. Но это, думаю, очень неэффективный подход.

Comment: хорошо, буду знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char * sym = "5";
int res = atoi(sym);
```

или

```
char sym[2] = {0};
sym[0] = '5';
int res = atoi(sym);
```

Или, ежели именно один `char` от `'0` до '`9`' - то

```
int res = sym-'0';
```